# How to use componentWillReceiveProps in functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm new to functional components after spending some huge time with class components.While trying out something, I ran into some problems. How to use `componentWillReceiveProps` in the context of `useEffect` hook,

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (_.isEmpty(nextProps.user)) {
    this.props.history.push("/signin");
  }
  this.setState({
    selImg: nextProps.meetingData.themeImage,
  });
}
```

Comment: Please share your functional component as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Wrap the side effect of changing the route in a `useEffect()`, and make it dependent on `user`, so it would react whenever `user` changes. You also need to `history` as a dependency, but it wouldn't change.
- Assign `meetingData.themeImage` to a `const` or use it directly, since the component will rerender anyway if it changes.

  ```
  const Example = ({ user, history, meetingData }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      if (_.isEmpty(user)) {
        history.push("/signin");
      }  
    }, [user, history]);

    const selImg = meetingData.themeImage;

    return (
      // JSX
    );
  }
  ```

Comment: Just a small correction, shouldn't it be `props.history`instead of `this.props.history` and `props` instead of `nextProps`?

Comment: Good points. I've actually destructured them from the props, but forgot to change the original.

Answer (score 1):

This could be equivalent to `useEffect` with dependency in functional component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (_.isEmpty(props.user)) {
    props.history.push("/signin");
  }
  setState({
    selImg: props.meetingData.themeImage,
  });
}, [props.user]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the functional implementation for your code.

Instead of `setState` you can use `useState`, instead of `componentWillReceiveProps` you can listen to updates of variables using `useEffect`.
Note `useEffect`'s second argument, the dependencies array. There you can choose what updates will trigger `useEffect`'s first variable (i.e. the callback).

```
function FunctionalImplementation({ user, history, meetingData }) {
  // The functional equivalent of `this.state = { selImg: null }`
  const [selImg, setSelImg] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (_.isEmpty(user)) {
      history.push("/signin");
    }
    
    // You might want to put this inside an `else` block, just to be more clear
    setSelImg(meetingData.themeImage);

    // If you want to update `selImg` when `props.meetingData` changes too,
    // add it to useEffect's dependencies array
  }, [user, history]);
}
```